# OpenMP Transpose Matrix

Tags: c, matrix, openmp, transpose

I'm trying to improve the efficiency of transposing a square matrix. Here is the naive way of doing it (MSIZE is the length of the square matrix):

```
int i,j;
for(i=0; i<MSIZE; i++) 
  for(j=0; j<MSIZE; j++)
     d[j][i]=c[i][j];
```

This runs in about 7 seconds.

I realized that I can improve it by blocking, so I successfully did it and integrated some parallelization with it. I got it down to 0.5 seconds.

```
int i,j, row, col;
int blocksize = 16;

#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, row, col) schedule(static, 2)
for ( i = 0; i < MSIZE; i += blocksize) {
    for ( j = 0; j < MSIZE; j += blocksize) {
        for (row = i; row < i + blocksize && row < MSIZE; row++) {
            for (col = j; col < j + blocksize && col < MSIZE; col++) {
                d[row][ col] = c[col][row];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my goal is to try to reduce this as much as possible. I am willing to go back to the naive way and parallelize that if i really cannot parallelize blocking method anymore. Any ideas how to improve the time efficiency?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/37502898/620382. Still missing essential information such as CPU &, memory specifications,  `MSIZE`, compiler,  compiler flags. Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: you should define `imax = min( i+blocksize, MSIZE )` right inside you `i` loop, and likewise for `jmax`... Using them inside your `row` and `col` loop termination tests might spare you some cycles.

Comment: C doesn't have a min or max function apparently. also i used many other suggestions to make one including my own min() and it slowed down the code